# See traceback of loaddata command (when error)

Tags: python, django, traceback

I'm trying to load fixture:

> python manage.py loaddata stock/fixtures/initial_data.json

But error occurred without traceback (I don't know which model is the problem):

```
ValueError: Problem installing fixture 'stock/fixtures/initial_data.json': The database backend does not accept 0 as a value for AutoField.
```

How get the traceback?

Comment: You should get it as a part of your error message, what IDE are you using or is this just command line?

Comment: It's a command line. So no more output.

Comment: Your fixture contains `0` as identifier for an object. Is the fixture file small enough for manual inspection?

Comment: Good idea ! I found the line in json file. Thank's ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a --traceback option.

```
python manage.py loaddata stock/fixtures/initial_data.json --traceback
```

This isn't mentioned in the [loaddata docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/django-admin/#loaddata-fixture-fixture), it's part of the [default command options](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/django-admin/#django-admin-option---traceback).

Comment: Shame on me, i forgott Read The F**** Manual ! (python manage.py help loaddata). Thank's !